# Fancybox css issue

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I use fancybox into a html page but i can't style the link to open the fancybox. Normaly i use a class to style the html link but with fancybox the class is already given to the fancybox. I need to change the background color of the link liks this:

```
background-color: #E9F3D8;
```

Here is the fancybox script i use into the html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".contactForm").fancybox({
        'width'         : 750,
        'height'        : 420,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'type'          : 'iframe'
    });
});
</script>
```

And the link into this page looks linke this

```
<a href="../waar-vind-je-ons/contact_form.php" class="contactForm">mail</a>
```

Comment: you can add as many classes to an element as you want, use one to bind fancybox and the other to style it, or you can actually style the same class, which fancybox is bound it to

Answer (score 0):

Hard to recreate problem with jsfiddle because all work fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zgfLefLt/)

```
<style>
    a {
    background-color: #E9F3D8;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".contactForm").fancybox({
        'width'         : 750,
        'height'        : 420,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'type'          : 'iframe'
    });
});
</script>
```

Maybe give more details that we can help you or maybe I do something wrong with recreating.